# Verify a signature or confirm a signature

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-request

I'm making an online petition and after somebody signs my petition, I will send an email to make sure that the email address belongs to right person. Should I write **verify a signature** or **confirm a signature**? The White House's petition service uses the word **verify** but UK Government's petition service uses the word **confirm**.

Comment: 'Verify' generally means that you check something by keeping something 'parallel'. So, you verify a signature by keeping the original signature in other hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using email, you can **verify** or **confirm** that the email address is **valid** by sending the recipient an email to a target address and asking them **to reply or click on a link**.

It is **not possible to verify** a signature via **email alone**. It could be anyone(!) **Signature verification** usually requires watching someone write their name and checking it against a **known sample** of their signature. For example, the back of a credit card. Banks are very cautious about this and usually require a personal interview the first time.

If you are using an email address as an electronic signature, then you would be asking to **verify** the email address belongs to the appropriate owner, and they would **confirm** that it is theirs.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you should use "please *confirm* your signature."

Just as Maulik suggested in the comment, *verify* typical means you are comparing two things.  Usually one is a source document that you know is accurate.  If the second signature matches the source document, you have verified the second signature is accurate.

In your case, it sounds like you want the person to *confirm* that their signature is truly their signature.  *Confirm* works well in this situation.

Depending on your profession, another way to say the same would be to use "Please attest to your signature."   This is used in the Audit world often (of which I am a part), as well as other professions.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to rechecking something (here, a signature), you could use any of the following terms :

> - Verify
> - Check
> - Double-check
> - Cross-check (by using an alternative source)
> - Confirm
> - Review

Out of which, my personal suggestion would be **'Double-check'**, but it may sound informal. For formal usage, I would suggest **'Verify'**, as it sounds a bit for official than *"check"*.